# No me abre el navigation drawer

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estoy implementando el navigation drawer en una aplicacion kotlin. Aparece en la toolbar pero no responde cuando le doy click.

Los xmls correspondientes al navigation estan identicos a cuando el ide los implementa.

No tira error ni nada como si no tuviera el listener activado cuando le doy click.

Soy muy nuevo en kotlin y en android. Si necesitan que copie mas fuentes me avisan  no hay drama desde ya muchas gracias.

Me hice un proyecto nuevo y implemente el navigation drawer tal cual y funciona me debe faltar algo tonto

Copio el codigo kotlin:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

companion object {
    val MODALIDAD = "MODALIDAD"
    val AGREGAR = 1
}
private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
private lateinit var username: EditText
private lateinit var password: EditText
private lateinit var logIn: RelativeLayout
private lateinit var createUser: TextView
private lateinit var nombre: String
private var saludar: Boolean = false
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarmav)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)


    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    )
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)



    setupUI()
    initilizeLogIn()
    initializeToolbar()
    initilizeCreateUser()
    asignarValoresSettings()

    if (saludar) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hola $nombre", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}



override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home -> {
            // Handle the camera action
        }
        R.id.nav_gallery -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_slideshow -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_tools -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_share -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_send -> {

        }
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}

private fun asignarValoresSettings() {
    val pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)

    nombre = pref.getString("etPrefNombre", "Emiliano")
    saludar = pref.getBoolean("chkPrefSaludar", false)
}

private fun initilizeLogIn() {
    logIn.setOnClickListener {
        if (completeInfo()) {
            logIn()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Completar datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }
}

private fun logIn() {
    var username = etUsername.text.toString()
    var password = etPassword.text.toString()
    val db = DBHelper(this)
    if (db.search(username, password)) {
        goToTournaments()
        finish()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Datos incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}

private fun initializeBtnSettings() {
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SettingsActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
}
private fun initilizeCreateUser() {
    createUser.setOnClickListener {
        goToCreateUser()
    }
}

private fun goToCreateUser() {
    val activityInsert = Intent(this, CreateUserActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(activityInsert)
}

private fun completeInfo(): Boolean {
    return !etPassword.text.toString().isEmpty() &&
            !etUsername.text.toString().isEmpty()
}

private fun initializeToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.setTitle(R.string.app_name)
  //  supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

}

private fun setupUI() {
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarmav)
    username = findViewById(R.id.etUsername)
    password = findViewById(R.id.etPassword)
    logIn = findViewById(R.id.btnLogIn)
    createUser = findViewById(R.id.btnCreateUser)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar1_menu, menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}

private fun showHelp() {
    var builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Ayuda")
        .setMessage("Crea tournaments o visualiza los enfrentamientos")
        .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ -> }
        .setCancelable(false)
        .show()
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.menuAyuda -> showHelp()
        //android.R -> onBackPressed()
        R.id.btnSettings -> initializeBtnSettings()
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}



private fun goToTournaments() {
    val activityInsert = Intent(this, ListTournamentsActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(activityInsert)
}
```

}

copio xml de la activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <include
                layout="@layout/app_bar_navigation_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUsername"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#11000000"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Usuario"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#11000000"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Contraseña"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etUsername"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etUsername" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnCreateUser"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/btnLogIn">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="Ingresar"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnCreateUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Registrate."
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/twitter" />

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/instagram" />

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/facebook" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation_drawer"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para abrir el navigationDrawer debe realizarse de esta forma:

```
drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
```

En el método onNavigationItemSelected() en realidad lo estas cerrando siempre, debes cambiar a :

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home -> {
            // Handle the camera action
        }
        R.id.nav_gallery -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_slideshow -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_tools -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_share -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_send -> {

        }
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    //drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)

     //* Abre Navigation Drawer.
     drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)    

     return true
}
```